# Shared resources for two Apps from the same developer

Tags: objective-c, ios, conceptual

Is it possible that AppA and AppB which are from the same developer share some local resources on a given device. For example they might use the same login credentials for some service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps cannot share files.

But they can share keychain access to store login credentials using keychain-access-groups. You have to set this up in the "Entitlements" section in the project summary.

Comment: Apart from Login credentials, can we store NSData (A Stream of Data) or a String?

Comment: @SandeepTDS This answer is five years old and no longer true. Apps can share files, defaults and other data via various means.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not share resources on the device directly but you can let them sync by iCloud.

[iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html) allows you share resources between different devices, so why not between different application on the same device?

Sure there are some restriction with this approach, e.g. network connection, data size,..  but for some UseCases this might be a approach

Comment: please leave a comment with a reason if you think this answer is not useful, this approach works and i use it in one of my application

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, I am using App Groups to share data between apps. An App Group allows multiple apps developed by the same team to access one or more shared containers. See Apple documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups

Answer (score -1):

Apps are sandboxed and can't share resources.

Comment: -1 They can share a lot of resources: asset library, address book, calendar, pasteboard, ... Apps cannot share files easily, though.